# ASP.NET MVC HTML How can I create a button that changes the form, not submitting it

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create buttons in a form, which doesn't submit the form. I have a button to submit the form, and that's the only one I want to submit. The buttons that I wish to create should have access to all the form, without needing to reload (and loose data) the form.

My view is:

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Nº Encomenda</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="encID" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:lightgray;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Farmácia</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.cliNome" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Contactos</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.cliTelefone[0]" readonly="readonly" /><input asp-for="farmDetails.cliTelefone[1]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Rua</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.locRua" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Localidade</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.locLocalidade" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Código Postal</label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="farmDetails.locCodPostal" readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArm)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArm, Model.aSelVM.ArmList, "Seleccionar...")</td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArm)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArmLoc)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.aSelVM.SelectedArmLoc, Model.aSelVM.ArmLocList)</td>
        </tr>

        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProdPartialView", Model.pVM)

    </table>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" formaction="/Order/AddProdWnd" value="Adicionar" /><!--Adicionar</button>-->
        <input type="button" asp-action="RemoveProd" asp-controller="Order" value="Eliminar" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Origem da Venda &nbsp;
        <select asp-for="origemVenda" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<originSellType>()">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccionar...</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Prioritário &nbsp; <input asp-for="isPrioritario" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><label>Observações</label></p>
        <textarea asp-for="observs"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" asp-action="SendOrdForm" asp-controller="Order" />

</form>
```

The buttons "Adicionar", "Eliminar" are the one's that I am referring to.

I am using a very complex data structure, I know...

Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: So what's the issue you facing here, If you just want to do some client side changes use jquery or if it needs to be in server side use Jquery ajax and hook up..

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I have to use jQuery...